# Как строку перевести в список?

Tags: python

Есть такая строка: `"['014', '015', '016', '018']"`.
Как из этого сделать список в python, сохранив такой же вид?

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в общем много раз уже подобные вопросы тут отвечались.

```
from ast import literal_eval

lst = literal_eval("['014', '015', '016', '018']")
print(lst)
# ['014', '015', '016', '018']
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а почему не просто `eval`?

Comment: @АлексейР "Eval is evil" (c)  В `eval` можно выполнить что угодно, хоть форматирование диска. Лучше не рисковать, мало ли откуда строка пришла, которую нужно обработать. Этот способ через `literal_eval` - безопасный.