# Как преобразовать строку в список в python?

Tags: python

Как преобразовать строку '["hello","world"]' в список ["hello","world"]?
Пробовал exec.

Comment: Вот противоположный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054870/how-to-convert-list-into-string-with-quotes-in-python

Comment: eval('["hello","world"]')

Comment: Сергей Ш. Спасибо большое! Помогло!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1475319/416121

Comment: Что всё так сложно? Exec это же зло. Надо просто так: `import json; json.loads('["hello","world"]')`.

Comment: я не пользую json, а использую собственную разработку.